# Static file issue when deploying an Django app

Tags: python, django, django-templates, web-deployment

I understand there are some existing problems/answers about loading static files in production.

However, my case is somehow different. My Django app not is deployed as the main app of my website (not in the public_html folder in the server), but an additional app (in a folder outside public_html). The server folder directory is like this

```
home/myaccount/
├── public_html
|      └── static (not exist, location 1)
├── mydjango
       └── static (generated by collectstatic, location 2)
            └── css, fonts etc.
```

In my settings.py, `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')` and `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`.

Currently, the browser will look for static files in the non-existing location 1, i.e., `www.mypage.com/static/...`, instead of location 2. 404 errors return.

My question is that how I can change `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` or other settings to make the browser look for location 2 instead of location 1?

Comment: Deploying your Django site outside public_html is not "different", it is *the recommended way to do it*. There is no reason why the Django app should be inside the web document root.

Comment: Do you have reverse proxy server? Apache, Nginx? Django is not made for serving static files.

Comment: did you try `python manage.py collectstatic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Linux server then an easier solution is to create a **symbolic link** of location 2 static folder in location 1.

```
ln -s /home/myaccount/mydjango/static /home/myaccount/public_html/static
```

Another solution can be to create STATIC_ROOT path to point to public_html folder.

Comment: Or update the Apache configuration to point /static/ at the STATIC_ROOT.